# @Value annotation is not injecting property value

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I was trying to get file path from property file using `@Value` annotation, but getting Null.

My Property File is like

```
filepath=file:/src/main/resources/usmr/input/redemption.txt
```

My xml File is like that

```
<bean id="USMRFileReader" class="com.aexp.earn.api.batch.util.readers.USMRFileReader" />
<util:properties id="batchProps" 
    location="classpath:earn-api-batch_e0.properties" />

<batch:job id="balancingUSMRFileJob">
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="USMRFileReader" writer="ControlReportWriter" processor="USMRListProcessor" commit-interval="1"></batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

And My Java file is like that

```
@Component(value = "USMRFileReader")
@Scope("step")
public class USMRFileReader implements ItemReader<String> {
private static final Logger ILOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerUtil.LOGGER_BATCH);

@Value("${batchProps['filepath']}")
private Resource resource;
```

But while executing this, null value is passing in resource variable.

Please Help

Comment: which Spring version are you using?

Comment: avoid mixing java and xml config; is the source of a lot of problems like the one you encountered

Answer (score 0):

You can easy do that via `@PropertySource` annotation. So, for example your class should have `@PropertySource` annotation like this:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:earn-api-batch_e0.properties")
@Component(value = "USMRFileReader")
@Scope("step")
public class USMRFileReader implements ItemReader<String> { ... }
```

Then inject your resource:

```
@Value("${filepath}")
private Resource resource;
```

And voila! Trick is done.

Also, make sure you have `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` defined somewhere in order to read properties:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

Comment: adding as per your suggestion ...but still i am getting null

Answer (score 0):

You can use `property-placeholder` instead of `util:properties`

Replace this

```
<util:properties id="batchProps" 
    location="classpath:earn-api-batch_e0.properties" />
```

with below

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:earn-api-batch_e0.properties"/>
```

Then you can get the property value from component:

```
@Component(value = "USMRFileReader")
@Scope("step")
public class USMRFileReader implements ItemReader<String> {
private static final Logger ILOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerUtil.LOGGER_BATCH);

@Value("${filepath}")
private String resource;
```

**EDIT:**

Add `context` namespace in your configuration file

```
<beans xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">
```

Comment: while adding property-placeholder, i am getting this error "The prefix "context" for element "context:property-placeholder" is not bound."

Comment: @RajnishShukla, you need to add it in DTD of your xml file, edited my answer, please check

Comment: still i am getting null

Answer (score -1):

Inject the complete environment into a bean and debug it in order to see, which properties are really loaded from which resource.

```
@Environment
private Environment env;
```

The Environment implements the PropertyResolver interface, which is your gate to all properties, that are loaded by the spring context. Debug the concrete implementation, that is injected.

Check if your file is really being loaded and that the property is there. Check if it is not somehow overwritten and set to null by something with a higher precedence.

If the property is in the Environment (you can check that easily by simply calling `env.getProperty("filepath")`), then this means, that your @Value annotation does not resolve the SPEL expression. This happens if you don't have

```
@Bean
public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

in a class that is handled by the component-scan.